# How to listen to property change of an object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to google maps api and js in general.
I have a project with 2 circle objects and they can change radius and center coordinates, every time one of those properties change I want to execute a specific function.
The radius of the circle changes with a controller press (setradius method), also the circles are draggable. I don't want to execute the function every frame while the user drags the circle(maybe checking after 0.1 sec if the properties didn't change and only then execute).
Hope I didn't make it too complicated.

**TL;DR:** how to execute a function every time the properties of a circle changes?

Comment: Since you mention "controller", what framework are you using client-side?  And, can you add to your question an example of some code that changes the radius?

Comment: For the controller I use the build in controler options in google maps, got the reference from here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom-state). I change the radius with a simple function like so:  function(circle) {circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius() * 1.1};  this function makes the given circle 10% larger

Comment: If you always change the radius from the same set of functions, then just make a new function called `updateRadius()` and call it in the function where you change the radius.

Comment: What function do you want to execute every time the radius changes? What does your code look like?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what your code looks like and what you have tried that you thought should work.

Comment: I can add the wanted function(the one I need to execute on property change of the circle) to every controller that changes the radius but I still need to take care of dragging the circle - how I execute the function after the circle got dragged to a new location?

Comment: The answer geocodezip provided did answer my initial question, as I already mentioned I'm new to js and didn't get the event based programming but  geocodezip's example gave me the basics I needed.    And also I did solve the problem with the function executing every frame of the drag - I used `google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'dragend', radiusChanged);` instead of  'center_changed'     and now the function executes only after the drag ends. Thank you for the help and sorry for complicated question, next time I will try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 is event based.  A [google.maps.Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle) has events that fire when any of its properties changes.  Add an event listener to your circles to listen for the radius_changed event.

```
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'radius_changed', radiusChanged);
```

working code snippet based on the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple):

```js
// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2714856
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8405837
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  population: 3857799
};
citymap['vancouver'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1),
  population: 603502
};

var cityCircle;

function radiusChanged() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "<b>" + this.title + "</b><br>radius=" + this.radius.toFixed(2) + " km";
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true,
      title: city,
      map: map,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(cityCircle, 'radius_changed', radiusChanged);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```